# ERROR [WsdlTestCase] Failed to create test step for [X]

Tags: maven, soapui

I get this error `ERROR [WsdlTestCase] Failed to create test step for [X]` when executing my soapui project from Maven.

Tests work fine from the SOAPUI client software.  My Soap-ui.error log is empty.

There doesn't seem to be enough information to let me debug this - I'm guessing there's some dependency I'm missing, but my tests are fairly simple (REST requests with a few assertions on the HTTP response). I assumed the core maven plugin would suffice.

My maven config is as below  (I've also included the eviware repository -http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>eviware</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <id>soapui-tests</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/MyTestSuite.xml</projectFile>
                        <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/soapui</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                        <printReport>true</printReport>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

the preceeding messages are :

```
[DefaultSoapUICore] Missing folder [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build-Mule-Configuration/workspace/ext] for external libraries 2015-07-01 15:10:48,961 INFO
[DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build-Mule-Configuration/workspace/soapui-settings.xml]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved up to the 4.6.1 version of the soapui plugin as detailed here
(http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html), the tests are now at least attempting to execute. As I understand it the version I've outlined above should work but perhaps it doesn't recognise the current SOAP UI project syntax.

As an aside the 4.6.1 version of the plugin  seems to have a much larger number of dependancies and for me is causing memory issues.

Comment: fwiw,  once I stopped some other services running from the same build (MockServer)  soapui finished downloading all its dependancies. for subsequent builds I was able to restart the MockServer.